# Watson training data format

Tags: json, artificial-intelligence, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I want Watson to train on certain data the user will provide in my web app - the data will be posted through forms.
My question is - which service in IBM Cloud matches this the best? I've tried Discovery, but it doesn't seem to be the best match for my request, first of all it does not want to accept .json or Excel formatted files, which seems like a red flag to me (concerning what I am looking for).

My ultimate goal is for Watson to learn the patterns and ultimately start providing suggestions for the user.

My data I give to Watson would look like this, .json format:

```json
{
        "songName" : "Beyond the sea",
        "artist" : "Bobby Darin",
        "genre" : "jazz"
}
```

Thank you in advance.

I've setup my IBM Cloud, enabled Discovery as a service, attempted to upload .json and excel files, from which both have been rejected.

I expected Watson to process the provided structured data, find patterns, and provide intelligent suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to build and train a model, then Watson Machine Learning service on IBM Cloud is what you are looking for. After you build and train a model, you deploy it and put it into production, so you can pass data to the model and get scoring data, also known as predictions, back.

You can access your deployment through an API endpoint, using the Watson Machine Learning Python client, CLI, or REST API (manually or in an application) to analyze data.

To know more about deploying your model, refer this the [documentation here](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/ml-deploy_new.html?linkInPage=true)

Also, there is a [code pattern](https://developer.ibm.com/patterns/build-a-product-recommendation-engine-with-watson-machine-learning/) that serves as an example of how to build a Machine Learning recommendation engine using Jupyter notebooks on Watson Studio